# Two column CV - Create box on top of the document

Tags: boxes, cv

does somebody know, how can I push this box under the address box?
[image]

I added this code:
[image]

I hope you can help me with this.

Best regards,
Gabriel

Main file:

```
%\title{My two column CV}
%
% tccv (two columns curriculum vitae) is a LaTeX class inspired by
% the template found at latextemplates.com by Alessandro Plasmati.
%
% Create by Nicola Fontana, the original files can be downloaded from:
% http://dev.entidi.com/p/tccv/
%
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\part{Patrick O'Hara}

\noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        PROFILE  \newline 
        Skilled with a strong sense of responsibility, effective interpersonal skills and the ability to contribute to teamwork – even in high pressure environments – seeking a career opportunity for personal and professional growth in administration, accounting or financial work, with a company where I would be an assets with my experience, expertise and language skills.
    }%
}

\section{Work experience}

\begin{eventlist}

\item{June 2009 -- Present}
     {Tim Hortons}
     {Server}

Servicing Canada's largest fast service restaurant chain whose sales records in baked goods and coffee have had remarkable impact on the Canadian food service industry. Attention had been paid to the provision of quality and timely service of thousands of daily customers.  

\item{June 2013 -- December 2013}
     {Phoenix Firestopping}
     {Firestopper}

Restoring fire-resistance of walls and floors in new housing structures by impeding the spread of hazardous flames with flame resistant materials.

\item{May 2012 -- November 2012}
     {Cornerstone Contractors}
     {Landscaper}

Modification of the visible features of an area of land in many forms namely gardening and planting, construction of patios and decks, and installation of drainage systems.

\end{eventlist}

\section{Education}

\begin{yearlist}

\item[Bachelor of Science]{2011 -- 2015}
     {Biology}
     {Dalhousie University, Halifax NS}

\item{2010 -- 2011}
     {Secondary School Diploma}
     {White Oaks Secondary School, Oakville ON}

\item{2008 -- 2010}
     {Secondary School}
     {American School of Dubai, Dubai UAE}

\item{2007 -- 2008}
     {Secondary School}
     {American School of Paris, Saint-Cloud FR}

\end{yearlist}
\personal
    [https://www.facebook.com/patrick.
    ohara.718]
    {312 Poplar Drive, Oakville, ON}
    {(902) 441 5181}
    {ohara.ptf@gmail.com}

\section{Extra Curricular Activities}

\begin{yearlist}

\item{2015}
     {Journey Canadian Tour}
     {Shadow Security Services}

\item{2015}
     {Bonnie Raitt}
     {Shadow Security Services}

\item{2014}
     {Freak Show Haunted Wharf}
     {Murphy's The Cable Wharf}

\item{2010}
     {Big Brother Program}
     {American School of Dubai}

\item{2010}
     {Beach Blast for children with disability}
     {American School of Dubai}

\end{yearlist}

\section{Communication skills}

\begin{factlist}
\item{English}{Native speaker}
\item{French}{Oral: intermediate; written: poor}
\end{factlist}

\section{Achievements}

\begin{yearlist}

\item{2015}
     {Bachelors Degree}

\item{2011}
     {Honor Roll}

\item{2010}
     {Eastern Mediterranean Volleyball Champions}

\item{2010}
     {Honor Roll}

\item{2010}
     {District Coastal Conference Volleyball Champions}

\end{yearlist}

\section{Computer skills}

\begin{factlist}

\item{Good level}
     {Microsoft Office, email, social networking}

\item{Basic level}
     {GitHub, HTML}

\end{factlist}

\end{document}
```

Header file:

```
% Copyright (C) 2012  Nicola Fontana <ntd at entidi.it>
%
% This program can be redistributed and/or modified under
% the terms of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3 of this license or (at your option) any later
% version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all LaTeX distributions
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% Based on the original idea by Alessandro Plasmati found at
% http://www.latextemplates.com/template/two-column-one-page-cv
%
% The most relevant changes from his work are:
%
% * this is a class, not a template document;
% * tccv is based on scrartcl (from Koma-script), not on article;
% * the fonts are selected from the PSNFSS collection, so no
%   custom font installation should be required;
% * heavily based the implementation on custom environments and
%   macros, so the document is much easier to read (and customize);
% * it is plain LaTeX/Koma-script, so the CV can be compiled
%   with the usual tools, latex and pdflatex included.

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{tccv}
              [2012/11/09 v1.0
 Two Column Curriculum Vitae]

\LoadClass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=1.25cm,vmargin=1.25cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1.25cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{bookman,etoolbox,hyperref,marvosym,needspace,tabularx,xcolor}

% Capitalize words of at least a minimum length (default to 3 chars).
% The text is capitalized before being expanded.
%
% This macro uses Lua to do the job but fails gracefully (that is,
% return the text as is) if \directlua is not available.
%
% |[
% \ucwords[optional: miminum length]{text}
% ]|
\newcommand\ucwords[2][3]{%
    % Fails gracefully if not in LuaLaTeX
    \providecommand\directlua[1]{#2}%
    \directlua{%
    local minlen=tonumber("#1")
    local src="\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}"
    local dst={}
    for w in src:gmatch('[^\string\%s]+') do
        if w:len() >= minlen then w = w:sub(1,1):upper()..w:sub(2) end
        table.insert(dst, w)
    end
    tex.print(dst)}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\color[HTML]{801010} % Default foreground color
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060} % Hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=link,linkcolor=link}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}}
\setkomafont{section}{\scshape\Large\mdseries}

% In tccv \part must contain the subject of the curriculum vitae.
% The command will start a new page and output in onecolumn the
% subject (first and last name) with the hardcoded text
% "Curriculum vitae" under it.
\renewcommand\part[1]{%
    \twocolumn[%
    \begin{center}
    \vskip-\lastskip%
    {\usekomafont{part} #1} \medskip\\
    {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\Huge Resume}
    \bigskip
    \end{center}]}

% Overrides the \section command to capitalize every
% word for cosmetic purposes and draws a rule under it.
\makeatletter
\let\old@section\section
\renewcommand\section[2][]{%
    \old@section[#1]{\ucwords{#2}}%
    \newdimen\raising%
    \raising=\dimexpr-0.7\baselineskip\relax%
    \vskip\raising\hrule height 0.4pt\vskip-\raising}
\makeatother

% Allow conditionals based on the job name. This can usually be set
% from a command-line argument: check fausto.en.tex for an example.
%
% |[
% \ifjob{jobname}{content if matches}{content if does not match}
% ]|
\newcommand\ifjob[3]{%
    \edef\JOBNAME{\jobname}%
    \edef\PIVOT{\detokenize{#1}}%
    \ifdefstrequal{\JOBNAME}{\PIVOT}{#2}{#3}%
}

% Renders a personal data box:
%
% |[
% \personal[optional: web site without scheme (no http:// prefix)]
%          {address}{phone number}{email}
% ]|
\newcommand\personal[4][]{%
    \needspace{0.5\textheight}%
    \newdimen\boxwidth%
    \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
    \colorbox[HTML]{EDC9AF}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|X}
    \Writinghand & {#2}\smallskip\\
    \Telefon     & {#3}\smallskip\\
    \Letter      & \href{mailto:#4}{#4}
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \Lightning & \href{http://#1}{#1}}
    \end{tabularx}}}

% Every \item can be followed by one or more paragraphs
% of description:
%
% |[
% \item{date range}{company}{role}
%
% Description of what achieved during this application.
% ]|
    \newenvironment{eventlist}{%
    \newcommand*\inskip{}
    \renewcommand\item[3]{%
    \inskip%
    {\raggedleft\sc ##1\\[1pt]}
    {##2}\\[2pt]
    {\Large\it ##3}
    \medskip
    \renewcommand\inskip{\bigskip}}}
    {\bigskip}

% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item[optional: what has been achieved]{years}{subject}{notes}
% ]|
\newenvironment{yearlist}{%
    \renewcommand\item[4][]{%
    {\sc ##2} & {\bfseries ##3} \\
    \ifstrempty{##1}{}{& {\sc ##1} \\}
    & {\it ##4}\medskip\\}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
    {\endtabularx}


% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item{fact}{description}
% ]|
\newenvironment{factlist}{%
    \newdimen\unbaseline
    \unbaseline=\dimexpr-\baselinestretch\baselineskip\relax
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    \textsc{##1} & {\raggedright ##2\medskip\\}\\[\unbaseline]}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
    {\endtabularx}
%%
%% End of file `tccv.cls'.
```

Comment: Where's `tccv` class from?

Comment: To be honest with you: I don`t remember, where I´ve downloaded the files :-/ It seems from: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/two-column-one-page-cv

Comment: @Gabriel: Can you please specify, where the 'olive' coloured box should appear precisely? Below the `Profile` box, in the right-handed column?

Comment: @Christian: exactly! The "olive" coloured box shall be placed under the profile box. In the right-handed column

Comment: @Gabriel: It looks 'olive' here in my browser :D

Comment: Hm, the problem is, that you placed a box at the top of a twocolumn - setup page. The address - box is basically placed at the right position, but is just overprinting the `parbox`.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is the `two-column` mode or the usage of `\fbox...` (the Profile box) which leaks one column to the other one.

The brownish `address` box is placed at the right position (from the sense of `two-column`, but of course, this will overprint the framed box from above.

I am not a fan of editing class files, but this seemed to be the easiest way: Removing `twocolumn` and adding the `multicol` package, which allows for explicitly breaking the column and adding the brown box at the top of the second column.

Note `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}` is not an option here, since even with `\usepackage{dblfloatfix}` this will not prevent the box floating away, since the `[h]` specifier does not work.

```
%\title{My two column CV}
%
% tccv (two columns curriculum vitae) is a LaTeX class inspired by
% the template found at latextemplates.com by Alessandro Plasmati.
%
% Create by Nicola Fontana, the original files can be downloaded from:
% http://dev.entidi.com/p/tccv/
%
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}


\part{Patrick O'Hara}

% Must be placed here!
\setlength{\linewidth}{\the\textwidth}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.25cm}


\fbox{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{%
 {\centering

  PROFILE%

 }
  Skilled with a strong sense of responsibility, effective interpersonal skills and the ability to contribute to teamwork – even in high pressure environments – seeking a career opportunity for personal and professional growth in administration, accounting or financial work, with a company where I would be an assets with my experience, expertise and language skills.
}
}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Work experience}

\begin{eventlist}

\item{June 2009 -- Present}
     {Tim Hortons}
     {Server}

Servicing Canada's largest fast service restaurant chain whose sales records in baked goods and coffee have had remarkable impact on the Canadian food service industry. Attention had been paid to the provision of quality and timely service of thousands of daily customers.  

\item{June 2013 -- December 2013}
     {Phoenix Firestopping}
     {Firestopper}

Restoring fire-resistance of walls and floors in new housing structures by impeding the spread of hazardous flames with flame resistant materials.

\item{May 2012 -- November 2012}
     {Cornerstone Contractors}
     {Landscaper}

Modification of the visible features of an area of land in many forms namely gardening and planting, construction of patios and decks, and installation of drainage systems.

\end{eventlist}

\section{Education}

\begin{yearlist}

\item[Bachelor of Science]{2011 -- 2015}
     {Biology}
     {Dalhousie University, Halifax NS}

\item{2010 -- 2011}
     {Secondary School Diploma}
     {White Oaks Secondary School, Oakville ON}

\item{2008 -- 2010}
     {Secondary School}
     {American School of Dubai, Dubai UAE}

\item{2007 -- 2008}
     {Secondary School}
     {American School of Paris, Saint-Cloud FR}

\end{yearlist}

\columnbreak

\personal
    [https://www.facebook.com/patrick.
    ohara.718]
    {312 Poplar Drive, Oakville, ON}
    {(902) 441 5181}
    {ohara.ptf@gmail.com}



\section{Extra Curricular Activities}

\begin{yearlist}

\item{2015}
     {Journey Canadian Tour}
     {Shadow Security Services}

\item{2015}
     {Bonnie Raitt}
     {Shadow Security Services}

\item{2014}
     {Freak Show Haunted Wharf}
     {Murphy's The Cable Wharf}

\item{2010}
     {Big Brother Program}
     {American School of Dubai}

\item{2010}
     {Beach Blast for children with disability}
     {American School of Dubai}

\end{yearlist}

\section{Communication skills}

\begin{factlist}
\item{English}{Native speaker}
\item{French}{Oral: intermediate; written: poor}
\end{factlist}

\section{Achievements}

\begin{yearlist}

\item{2015}
     {Bachelors Degree}

\item{2011}
     {Honor Roll}

\item{2010}
     {Eastern Mediterranean Volleyball Champions}

\item{2010}
     {Honor Roll}

\item{2010}
     {District Coastal Conference Volleyball Champions}

\end{yearlist}

\section{Computer skills}

\begin{factlist}

\item{Good level}
     {Microsoft Office, email, social networking}

\item{Basic level}
     {GitHub, HTML}

\end{factlist}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

**Modified tccv.cls**

```
% Copyright (C) 2012  Nicola Fontana <ntd at entidi.it>
%
% This program can be redistributed and/or modified under
% the terms of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3 of this license or (at your option) any later
% version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all LaTeX distributions
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% Based on the original idea by Alessandro Plasmati found at
% http://www.latextemplates.com/template/two-column-one-page-cv
%
% The most relevant changes from his work are:
%
% * this is a class, not a template document;
% * tccv is based on scrartcl (from Koma-script), not on article;
% * the fonts are selected from the PSNFSS collection, so no
%   custom font installation should be required;
% * heavily based the implementation on custom environments and
%   macros, so the document is much easier to read (and customize);
% * it is plain LaTeX/Koma-script, so the CV can be compiled
%   with the usual tools, latex and pdflatex included.

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{tccv}
              [2012/11/09 v1.0
 Two Column Curriculum Vitae]

\LoadClass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=1.25cm,vmargin=1.25cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{bookman,etoolbox,hyperref,marvosym,needspace,tabularx,xcolor}
\RequirePackage{multicol}
% Capitalize words of at least a minimum length (default to 3 chars).
% The text is capitalized before being expanded.
%
% This macro uses Lua to do the job but fails gracefully (that is,
% return the text as is) if \directlua is not available.
%
% |[
% \ucwords[optional: miminum length]{text}
% ]|
\newcommand\ucwords[2][3]{%
    % Fails gracefully if not in LuaLaTeX
    \providecommand\directlua[1]{#2}%
    \directlua{%
    local minlen=tonumber("#1")
    local src="\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}"
    local dst={}
    for w in src:gmatch('[^\string\%s]+') do
        if w:len() >= minlen then w = w:sub(1,1):upper()..w:sub(2) end
        table.insert(dst, w)
    end
    tex.print(dst)}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\color[HTML]{801010} % Default foreground color
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060} % Hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=link,linkcolor=link}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{801010}}
\setkomafont{section}{\scshape\Large\mdseries}

% In tccv \part must contain the subject of the curriculum vitae.
% The command will start a new page and output in onecolumn the
% subject (first and last name) with the hardcoded text
% "Curriculum vitae" under it.
\renewcommand\part[1]{%
    \twocolumn[%
    \begin{center}
    \vskip-\lastskip%
    {\usekomafont{part} #1} \medskip\\
    {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\Huge Resume}
    \bigskip
    \end{center}]}

% Overrides the \section command to capitalize every
% word for cosmetic purposes and draws a rule under it.
\makeatletter
\let\old@section\section
\renewcommand\section[2][]{%
    \old@section[#1]{\ucwords{#2}}%
    \newdimen\raising%
    \raising=\dimexpr-0.7\baselineskip\relax%
    \vskip\raising\hrule height 0.4pt\vskip-\raising}
\makeatother

% Allow conditionals based on the job name. This can usually be set
% from a command-line argument: check fausto.en.tex for an example.
%
% |[
% \ifjob{jobname}{content if matches}{content if does not match}
% ]|
\newcommand\ifjob[3]{%
    \edef\JOBNAME{\jobname}%
    \edef\PIVOT{\detokenize{#1}}%
    \ifdefstrequal{\JOBNAME}{\PIVOT}{#2}{#3}%
}

% Renders a personal data box:
%
% |[
% \personal[optional: web site without scheme (no http:// prefix)]
%          {address}{phone number}{email}
% ]|
\newcommand\personal[4][]{%
    \needspace{0.5\textheight}%
    \newdimen\boxwidth%
    \boxwidth=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax%
    \colorbox[HTML]{EDC9AF}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\boxwidth}{c|X}
    \Writinghand & {#2}\smallskip\\
    \Telefon     & {#3}\smallskip\\
    \Letter      & \href{mailto:#4}{#4}
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\smallskip\\ \Lightning & \href{http://#1}{#1}}
    \end{tabularx}}}

% Every \item can be followed by one or more paragraphs
% of description:
%
% |[
% \item{date range}{company}{role}
%
% Description of what achieved during this application.
% ]|
    \newenvironment{eventlist}{%
    \newcommand*\inskip{}
    \renewcommand\item[3]{%
    \inskip%
    {\raggedleft\sc ##1\\[1pt]}
    {##2}\\[2pt]
    {\Large\it ##3}
    \medskip
    \renewcommand\inskip{\bigskip}}}
    {\bigskip}

% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item[optional: what has been achieved]{years}{subject}{notes}
% ]|
\newenvironment{yearlist}{%
    \renewcommand\item[4][]{%
    {\sc ##2} & {\bfseries ##3} \\
    \ifstrempty{##1}{}{& {\sc ##1} \\}
    & {\it ##4}\medskip\\}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
    {\endtabularx}


% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item{fact}{description}
% ]|
\newenvironment{factlist}{%
    \newdimen\unbaseline
    \unbaseline=\dimexpr-\baselinestretch\baselineskip\relax
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    \textsc{##1} & {\raggedright ##2\medskip\\}\\[\unbaseline]}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
    {\endtabularx}
%%
%% End of file `tccv.cls'.
```

[image]

Comment: Guys...great work! seriously... Do you know, how I can place the word "Profle" in the center (horizontal) ? Thank you really much! Just another thing: The box is not completly aligned to the right side. Do you know, how to align it?

Comment: @Gabriel: Well, that's actually not the content of your question. I'll try, but consider to accept the answer afterwards then

Comment: @Gabriel: See the update please, the one with `{\centering...}` in the profile-box. Note the `{...}` pair and the explicit empty lines!

Comment: Thank you, really! The box is not aligned on the right side. Do you know, how to align it? Sry.

Comment: @Gabriel: Your changing the question again :-(

Comment: I hate templates .... recent version of the class on gthub.

Comment: @Johannes_B: The `\twocolumn` approach is a design flaw.